# How to show time on next line?

Tags: php

I want a break after the date to display the time on the next line:

```
date_format($entrytime, 'd/m/Y "<br />" g:i A')
```

I also tried these:

```
date_format($entrytime, 'd/m/Y "\n" g:i A')
date_format($entrytime, 'd/m/Y "<br /><br />" g:i A')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
echo date_format($entrytime, 'd/m/Y').'</br>'.date_format($entrytime, 'g:i A');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape all non date formatting characters

```
<?php
$entrytime = new \DateTime();
echo date_format($entrytime, 'd/m/Y \<\b\r\> g:i A');
```